# HTML5 angular input() for Map

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass in a Map as input from HTML to angular component.
From instance: if I need to pass an array of strings ifekm HTML to Typescript: it looks like:

HTML5 
[strarray] = [‘hello’,’world]

Angular/TS file 
@Input() = String[]

I wanna pass a map of String, Array>

I can’t seem to figure out the syntax in HTML5.

Comment: Could you please refactor your code and provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Property inputs are passed as literals in Angular. Given a component of:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  template: `{{ strarray.join(', ') }}`
})
export class YourComponent {

  @Input()
  strarray: string[] = [];

}
```

Your implementation would be:

```
<your-component [strarray]="['one', 'two', 'three']"></your-component>
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5godg)